# Is it possible to generate java source files from a spring-beans.xsd which is generated from the spring-beans.dtd?

Tags: java, xml, spring, castor

I am trying to generate Java classes to bind xml to objects using castor. The piece of xml that I am trying to bind is a spring xml file so i took the dtd and generated the xsd using the tools castor provided, but once I attempt to generate the source files i recieve the following error

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Duplicate name found as a class member: _key
```

Here is the xsd file that I have generated:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="generated.castor.org">
<element name="entry">
    <complexType>
        <sequence>
            <element ref="key" minOccurs="0" />
            <choice minOccurs="0">
                <element ref="bean" />
                <element ref="ref" />
                <element ref="idref" />
                <element ref="value" />
                <element ref="null" />
                <element ref="list" />
                <element ref="set" />
                <element ref="map" />
                <element ref="props" />
            </choice>
        </sequence>
        <attribute name="value-ref" type="string" />
        <attribute name="key" type="string" />
        <attribute name="value" type="string" />
        <attribute name="key-ref" type="string" />
    </complexType>
</element>
<element name="arg-type">
    <complexType mixed="true">
        <attribute name="match" type="string" />
    </complexType>
</element>
<element name="bean">
    <complexType>
        <sequence>
            <element ref="description" minOccurs="0" />
            <choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <element ref="meta" />
                <element ref="constructor-arg" />
                <element ref="property" />
                <element ref="lookup-method" />
                <element ref="replaced-method" />
            </choice>
        </sequence>
        <attribute name="name" type="string" />
        <attribute name="id" type="ID" />
        <attribute name="class" type="string" />
        <attribute name="singleton" default="true">
            <simpleType>
                <restriction base="NMTOKEN">
                    <enumeration value="false" />
                    <enumeration value="true" />
                </restriction>
            </simpleType>
        </attribute>
        <attribute name="factory-method" type="string" />
        <attribute name="dependency-check" default="default">
            <simpleType>
                <restriction base="NMTOKEN">
                    <enumeration value="default" />
                    <enumeration value="simple" />
                    <enumeration value="none" />
                    <enumeration value="objects" />
                    <enumeration value="all" />
                </restriction>
            </simpleType>
        </attribute>
        <attribute name="lazy-init" default="default">
            <simpleType>
                <restriction base="NMTOKEN">
                    <enumeration value="default" />
                    <enumeration value="false" />
                    <enumeration value="true" />
                </restriction>
            </simpleType>
        </attribute>
        <attribute name="autowire-candidate" default="true">
            <simpleType>
                <restriction base="NMTOKEN">
                    <enumeration value="false" />
                    <enumeration value="true" />
                </restriction>
            </simpleType>
        </attribute>
        <attribute name="init-method" type="string" />
        <attribute name="autowire" default="default">
            <simpleType>
                <restriction base="NMTOKEN">
                    <enumeration value="default" />
                    <enumeration value="no" />
                    <enumeration value="byName" />
                    <enumeration value="autodetect" />
                    <enumeration value="byType" />
                    <enumeration value="constructor" />
                </restriction>
            </simpleType>
        </attribute>
        <attribute name="destroy-method" type="string" />
        <attribute name="abstract" default="false">
            <simpleType>
                <restriction base="NMTOKEN">
                    <enumeration value="false" />
                    <enumeration value="true" />
                </restriction>
            </simpleType>
        </attribute>
        <attribute name="depends-on" type="string" />
        <attribute name="parent" type="string" />
        <attribute name="factory-bean" type="string" />
    </complexType>
</element>
<element name="prop">
    <complexType mixed="true">
        <attribute name="key" type="string" use="required" />
    </complexType>
</element>
<element name="beans">
    <complexType>
        <sequence>
            <element ref="description" minOccurs="0" />
            <choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <element ref="import" />
                <element ref="alias" />
                <element ref="bean" />
            </choice>
        </sequence>
        <attribute name="default-destroy-method" type="string" />
        <attribute name="default-lazy-init" default="false">
            <simpleType>
                <restriction base="NMTOKEN">
                    <enumeration value="false" />
                    <enumeration value="true" />
                </restriction>
            </simpleType>
        </attribute>
        <attribute name="default-init-method" type="string" />
        <attribute name="default-dependency-check" default="none">
            <simpleType>
                <restriction base="NMTOKEN">
                    <enumeration value="simple" />
                    <enumeration value="none" />
                    <enumeration value="objects" />
                    <enumeration value="all" />
                </restriction>
            </simpleType>
        </attribute>
        <attribute name="default-autowire" default="no">
            <simpleType>
                <restriction base="NMTOKEN">
                    <enumeration value="no" />
                    <enumeration value="byName" />
                    <enumeration value="autodetect" />
                    <enumeration value="byType" />
                    <enumeration value="constructor" />
                </restriction>
            </simpleType>
        </attribute>
        <attribute name="default-merge" default="false">
            <simpleType>
                <restriction base="NMTOKEN">
                    <enumeration value="false" />
                    <enumeration value="true" />
                </restriction>
            </simpleType>
        </attribute>
    </complexType>
</element>
<element name="props">
    <complexType>
        <sequence>
            <element ref="prop" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </sequence>
        <attribute name="merge" default="default">
            <simpleType>
                <restriction base="NMTOKEN">
                    <enumeration value="default" />
                    <enumeration value="false" />
                    <enumeration value="true" />
                </restriction>
            </simpleType>
        </attribute>
    </complexType>
</element>
<element name="lookup-method">
    <complexType>
        <attribute name="bean" type="string" />
        <attribute name="name" type="string" />
    </complexType>
</element>
<element name="replaced-method">
    <complexType>
        <sequence>
            <element ref="arg-type" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </sequence>
        <attribute name="name" type="string" />
        <attribute name="replacer" type="string" />
    </complexType>
</element>
<element name="ref">
    <complexType>
        <attribute name="bean" type="string" />
        <attribute name="local" type="IDREF" />
        <attribute name="parent" type="string" />
    </complexType>
</element>
<element name="property">
    <complexType>
        <sequence>
            <element ref="description" minOccurs="0" />
            <element ref="meta" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            <choice minOccurs="0">
                <element ref="bean" />
                <element ref="ref" />
                <element ref="idref" />
                <element ref="value" />
                <element ref="null" />
                <element ref="list" />
                <element ref="set" />
                <element ref="map" />
                <element ref="props" />
            </choice>
        </sequence>
        <attribute name="name" type="string" use="required" />
        <attribute name="ref" type="string" />
        <attribute name="value" type="string" />
    </complexType>
</element>
<element name="import">
    <complexType>
        <attribute name="resource" type="string" use="required" />
    </complexType>
</element>
<element name="meta">
    <complexType>
        <attribute name="key" type="string" use="required" />
        <attribute name="value" type="string" use="required" />
    </complexType>
</element>
<element name="set">
    <complexType>
        <choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <element ref="bean" />
            <element ref="ref" />
            <element ref="idref" />
            <element ref="value" />
            <element ref="null" />
            <element ref="list" />
            <element ref="set" />
            <element ref="map" />
            <element ref="props" />
        </choice>
        <attribute name="value-type" type="string" />
        <attribute name="merge" default="default">
            <simpleType>
                <restriction base="NMTOKEN">
                    <enumeration value="default" />
                    <enumeration value="false" />
                    <enumeration value="true" />
                </restriction>
            </simpleType>
        </attribute>
    </complexType>
</element>
<element name="null">
    <complexType mixed="true" />
</element>
<element name="alias">
    <complexType>
        <attribute name="name" type="string" use="required" />
        <attribute name="alias" type="string" use="required" />
    </complexType>
</element>
<element name="value">
    <complexType mixed="true">
        <attribute name="type" type="string" />
    </complexType>
</element>
<element name="constructor-arg">
    <complexType>
        <sequence>
            <element ref="description" minOccurs="0" />
            <choice minOccurs="0">
                <element ref="bean" />
                <element ref="ref" />
                <element ref="idref" />
                <element ref="value" />
                <element ref="null" />
                <element ref="list" />
                <element ref="set" />
                <element ref="map" />
                <element ref="props" />
            </choice>
        </sequence>
        <attribute name="index" type="string" />
        <attribute name="type" type="string" />
        <attribute name="ref" type="string" />
        <attribute name="value" type="string" />
    </complexType>
</element>
<element name="description">
    <complexType mixed="true" />
</element>
<element name="list">
    <complexType>
        <choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <element ref="bean" />
            <element ref="ref" />
            <element ref="idref" />
            <element ref="value" />
            <element ref="null" />
            <element ref="list" />
            <element ref="set" />
            <element ref="map" />
            <element ref="props" />
        </choice>
        <attribute name="value-type" type="string" />
        <attribute name="merge" default="default">
            <simpleType>
                <restriction base="NMTOKEN">
                    <enumeration value="default" />
                    <enumeration value="false" />
                    <enumeration value="true" />
                </restriction>
            </simpleType>
        </attribute>
    </complexType>
</element>
<element name="map">
    <complexType>
        <sequence>
            <element ref="entry" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </sequence>
        <attribute name="value-type" type="string" />
        <attribute name="key-type" type="string" />
        <attribute name="merge" default="default">
            <simpleType>
                <restriction base="NMTOKEN">
                    <enumeration value="default" />
                    <enumeration value="false" />
                    <enumeration value="true" />
                </restriction>
            </simpleType>
        </attribute>
    </complexType>
</element>
<element name="idref">
    <complexType>
        <attribute name="bean" type="string" />
        <attribute name="local" type="IDREF" />
    </complexType>
</element>
<element name="key">
    <complexType>
        <choice>
            <element ref="bean" />
            <element ref="ref" />
            <element ref="idref" />
            <element ref="value" />
            <element ref="null" />
            <element ref="list" />
            <element ref="set" />
            <element ref="map" />
            <element ref="props" />
        </choice>
    </complexType>
</element>
```

Has anyone run into a similiar problem and know of any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the concrete castor problem you should provide more information, I guess. It seems there's a duplicate field, so go ahead and remove each "key" attribute one by one until it starts working.

But it is a strange thing you are trying to do. Spring's DTD/XSD are meant to provide XML configuration - they aren't supposed to represent objects. If you want to configure spring with code rather than xml, use [javaconfig](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java).

Comment: Thanks for the advice, i didn't know javaconfig existed. Unfortunately I don't think I'm able to make use of this library in my project. What I am trying to do was to wrap different parts of the spring files in a GUI to make it less intimidating to to non-programmers. The spring files would be accessed from a seperate project. Right now I'm parsing the spring xml files using the java dom parser but it seems like a lot more code than necessary.